# Create "is majority" indicator from a list of group memberships

Tags: stata

I have a set of dummy variables relating to group membership within a particular country:

```
     +------------------------------------+
     | group1   group2   group3   country |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0       FOO |
  2. |      0        0        1       FOO |
  3. |      0        0        1       FOO |
  4. |      0        1        0       BAR |
  5. |      1        0        0       BAR |
  6. |      1        0        0       BAR |
  7. |      1        0        0       BAR |
  8. |      1        0        0       BAR |
     +------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to create a new variable describing whether or not an individual is part of the majority group in a given country.

I would like to construct this indicator from my sample.  For example, in the data set shown, `group3` is the majority in country `FOO`, so individuals `2` and `3` are in the majority. In `BAR`, the majority group is `group1` and therefore individuals `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8` are in the majority.

Does anyone have a neat way of calculating the majority group in each country?

Comment: `help collapse` is one way. It's best if you provide an initial attempt, and request help indicating why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Majority here evidently means largest party, without necessarily 50% or more of the votes.

Here is a direct solution without using `egen`'s `mode()`. (I have no bias against that function; I was its first author.)

Note the possibility of ties. This code picks a group arbitrarily if there are ties, but flags that they exist. However, `mode()` has handles for ties.

```
clear 
input group1 group2 group3 str4 country 
 0 1 0 FOO 
 0 0 1 FOO 
 0 0 1 FOO 
 0 1 0 BAR 
 1 0 0 BAR 
 1 0 0 BAR 
 1 0 0 BAR 
 1 0 0 BAR 
 1 0 0 FROG 
 0 1 0 FROG
 0 0 1 FROG 
end 
gen group = group1
forval j = 2/3 { 
    replace group = `j' if group`j' 
} 
bysort country group: gen freq = _N 
bysort country (freq group): gen maj = group[_N] 
by country: gen maxfreq = freq[_N] 
bysort country freq (group): gen ties = group[1] != group[_N] & freq == maxfreq 

list, sepby(country)  

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | group1   group2   group3   country   group   freq   maj   maxfreq   ties |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0       BAR       2      1     1         4      0 |
  2. |      1        0        0       BAR       1      4     1         4      0 |
  3. |      1        0        0       BAR       1      4     1         4      0 |
  4. |      1        0        0       BAR       1      4     1         4      0 |
  5. |      1        0        0       BAR       1      4     1         4      0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |      0        1        0       FOO       2      1     3         2      0 |
  7. |      0        0        1       FOO       3      2     3         2      0 |
  8. |      0        0        1       FOO       3      2     3         2      0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |      1        0        0      FROG       1      1     3         1      1 |
 10. |      0        1        0      FROG       2      1     3         1      1 |
 11. |      0        0        1      FROG       3      1     3         1      1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, a good and important point about ties. (Although in my huge dataset, the probability is pretty small.) [My solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36019315/2071807) is more readable to my novice eyes, but yours is far more complete.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the dummy variables to a single categorical variable using `egen` and the `group` function.
2. Create a `majority` variable by calculating the mode (the most common value)
3. Test `group_membership` for equality to the mode, to find whether the individual is part of the majority

Here's the code to do those three steps:

```
. egen group_membership = group(group*)
. egen maj = mode(group_membership), by(country)
. gen is_maj = (group_membership == maj)
```

resulting in:

```
     +--------------------------------+
     | group   country   maj   is_maj |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |     2       FOO     3        0 |
  2. |     3       FOO     3        1 |
  3. |     3       FOO     3        1 |
  4. |     2       BAR     1        0 |
  5. |     1       BAR     1        1 |
     |--------------------------------|
  6. |     1       BAR     1        1 |
  7. |     1       BAR     1        1 |
  8. |     1       BAR     1        1 |
     +--------------------------------+
```